# Doesn't boot after fresh install

Tags: 11.10, boot, xorg, startup

After fresh install of oneiric 11.10 nothing displayed during boot process, but I still can switch to tty's. I made apt-get update/upgrade from tty and tried to reboot. Nothing changed. 'service lightdm restart' and 'startx' also doesn't help.

**UPD(24.10.2011):** Just reported bug with apport-bug to [launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/880898). You can see there logs and others collected reports.

Comment: nVidia Corporation C51G[GeForce 6100](rev a2)
also during startx there is an error string:
Failed to load module "nv" (module does not exists, 0)

Comment: No changes. Just 'nomodeset' caused ubuntu-logo with dots looks textual instead of graphical and less resolution for tty's. But it didn't help boot to DM. 'nomodeset xforcevesa' also doesn't led to desired. The same behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `sudo apt-get purge nvidia` replace nvidia by the driver you are using. It will use the free driver Nouveau.

That worked for me.

Comment: Thanks a lot. "sudo apt-get purge nvidia-173" was helpfull for me. Also I have to select Unity 2d in lightdm.

Comment: Will award you bounty tomorrow.

Comment: `sudo apt-get purge nvidia-173` worked for me also. Seems that the new 3.0 Linux kernel doesn't has the "nv" module... It's very messy having to fix that by hand. Also after booting the desktop, the visuals were a bit slow and after a while, the system hanged. Having been using Ubuntu for a while, I'm very dissappointed with Oneiric Ocelot. :(

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: No changes. Also tried 'sudo apt-get install --reinstall nvidia-173'

Comment: try `sudo apt-get install nvidia-current` since you are using a nvidia card, this will install the latest driver package for your system.

Comment: No changes. Package was not on my system, but installing it has not resolved an issue. PS. my VGA is integrated on motherboard.

Comment: Yeah, i have checked it, dont think your card is not supported anymore, just not sure its 100% supported. This is so weird :S the 'nv' module fault is the only thing you see faulty during boot?

Comment: All logs are available in launchpad bug. See **UPD**

Answer (score 0):

another way to restart the window manager should be

```
sudo initctl restart lightdm
```