# Graphics driver installation failure

Tags: graphics, login-screen

I have updated my AMD athlon computer with Ubuntu 11.04 to Ubuntu 11.10, and the installation was successful. The computer was working smoothly.

But when I installed the graphics driver it had suggested to me, the next time I booted  it did not work. The screen resolution of the initial login screen was off, and once I had logged in it had a very, very small resolution, and the display was all distorted. Much of the menubar was broken and everything in general looked distorted also. It after a few minutes went into a screen that checked my battery and other things, and then turned off.

Now when I turn on the computer I more often than not get a failed login screen that cannot display many of the components of the login screen.

I am a newbie to using ubuntu so sorry if this is a stupid question.

Thanks for your help in advance :D

**EDIT:**

These pictures show some of the login screen errors:

(Under GDE login option)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

OK. Just to make sure I'm understanding correctly. You are able to login, but the resolutions are wrong.

If that is the case, let's start with the simple things first. In the upper right hand corner you should see a "gear" icon. Click on it, then select 'System Settings' > Display.
From here select 'Detect Monitor'. After that, attempt to adjust your monitor settings.
(Caveat, I know this seems really simple, but some solutions are.)

If that didn't work. Return to the 'System Settings' window and select 'Hardware'.
From here, see what Video drivers are being offered. One of them is probably selected, and has a green bubble beside it. Select another driver, if available. Your best recourse may be to deselect the currently selected driver to see if it will use the Nuveau driver(or other default driver) instead. The Nuveau driver is non proprietary, and works well on most nVidia cards I've dealt with, but it doesn't support 3D rendering on serveral nVidia cards. I'm not as familiar with ATI cards, but a similar process should yield similar results.

Hope this is helpful. Please respond if helps/doesn't help or if I'm not understanding the situation properly.

Comment: I can't login >< I logged in once but that failed epicly, and I haven't been able to re-login since.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an nvidia video card.
You can remove the new driver and revert to the nuveau driver by opening a terminal and entering

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-173
```

I'm not certain but I beleive you can do a similar thing with ATI drivers as well if needed.

This link looks similar to what you're asking. [Doesn't boot after fresh install](https://askubuntu.com/q/70199/30357)

Comment: That isn't the same problem that I have because it displays the login screen. The solution didn't work for me. :O

Comment: I tried following the links you posted, but I get picasa reporting 'page not found'

Comment: Sorry the links are fixed now