# No monitor output after fresh install of 11.10 64-bit

Tags: 11.10, boot, nvidia, monitor

I have a machine with a Nvidia 8600GT graphics card and a CRT monitor.  Previously, I have only used Windows on it, and the graphics card seems to be working correctly in Windows 7.  I booted up and installed Ubuntu 11.10 amd64 from the LiveCD and the whole process worked perfectly.  When I tried to boot off the hard disk for the first time, the output to the monitor switched off during the splash screen, and this happens consistently.  I can ctrl-alt-f2, so I tried an `apt-get upgrade`, which didn't help; nor did `apt-get install nvidia-current`.  There is nothing that looks relevant in `dmesg`.  Booting with the `nomodeset` option has no effect.

Following the answers in [this similar thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70199/doesnt-boot-after-fresh-install), I tried `apt-get purge nvidia-173`.  Both `startx` and `service lightdm start` just say the service is already running.

Does anyone know how to find out what the problem is?  I was wondering if it is just that Ubuntu is trying to use a resolution that the monitor doesn't support, but I can't find out how to change that from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

Xorg might need to be reconfigured...

I had a similar situation.  This is what I did which gave me a graphical login screen after a restart:

```
sudo cp /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.bak
sudo cp /etc/X11/xorg.conf.failsafe /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

Here's the contents of my /etc/X11/xorg.conf.failsafe:

```
Section "Device"
   Identifier  "Configured Video Device"
   Driver      "fbdev"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
   Identifier  "Configured Monitor"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
   Identifier  "Default Screen"
   Monitor     "Configured Monitor"
   Device      "Configured Video Device"
EndSection
```

Something else you might look into:

```
Xorg -reconfigure
```

Something else you might look into is just removing the /etc/X11/xorg.conf file entirely and (restarting and) seeing what happens.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Unfortunately, I don't have a `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.failsafe`, and `Xorg` doesn't seem to have a `reconfigure` option.  I tried `Xorg -configure` from the recovery mode root shell (which is apparently needed to generate some of the `Xorg.conf` files in 11.10), and it fails with the message `Fatal server error: Could not create lock file in /tmp/.tX0-lock`.  I also discovered `xrandr` and tried playing with some of the output options to no avail.

Comment: Your `could not create lock file` error sounds like you might have a much larger issue--meaning, it might be easiest to just reinstall.  Other than that, I posted the contents of my failsafe config file just in case.